# IE 10 - div with scrollbar fires blur event causing it to hide (custom code)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, w2ui

We are using W2UI (Javascript UI) controls. It has a "Multi Select" input control with associated div container with suggestion data. Whenever user clicks on input control a suggestion div is popped up and user can select multiple items from the list. Please find below screenshot
[image]

We have set overfloaw:auto of div When suggestion list has more than 10 records. (Refer below screenshot)
[image]

At this point, clicking on scrollbar works fine in Chrome and Mozilla but in case of IE it closes / hides the div.

We have made initial RCA of this as follow. 
When a scrollbar is associated to a div, clicking on scrollbar causes blur event to fire for that div. 
In W2UI library, blur event is used to hide the suggestion div causing it to close. We also found that, clicking on scrollbar does not cause blur event to fire in chrome & firefox.

Now we want to suppress blur event when user clicks on "scrollbar" in case of IE.
We are unable to identify scrollbar click.

Please share your thoughts / workarounds about suppressing blur() event conditionally.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that IE's behaviour is *correct* here, because the scrollbar is a part of the webpage. Other browsers are handling scrollbars externally, producing arguably useful, but technically incorrect behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issue we have made some changes in w2ui lbrary
we have set global variable flagClick  first time it is false. & added below events

```
var div = $('#w2ui-global-items');
div.on('mouseover', function (event)
{                               
 flagClick = false;
 $('.w2ui-list').find('input').focus();

});
div.on('mouseout', function (event)
{
 flagClick = true;                               
 });
```

and changed blur event logic of div
as below --

```
.on('blur', function (event)
{
if (flagClick)
 {
 $(div).css('outline', 'none');
  obj.hide();
   if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation(); 
else event.cancelBubble = true;
  }
})
```

almost this logic have solved our issue, except one .
When we click on search textbox then list will populate , if after that we click on list scroolbar and after that click on  outside list div , List not getting hide (div blur event not getting fired).

try this solution , it will help u .
If you get solution to our problem pls post on same .

Answer (score 0):

An updated version of w2ui came out just a few days ago where controls, including multiselect, have been refactored. It seems to work fine for me with 1.4 version.